# BatmanJS: deeply nested routes

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, url-routing, batman.js

im wondering if anyone got something like this to work:

```
  @resources 'projects', ->
    @resources 'tables', ->
      @resources 'items'
```

with corresponding view content like:

```
%a{"data-bind" => "table.name", "data-route" => "routes.projects[project].tables[table]"}
  %div{"data-foreach-item" => "project.table.items"}
    %p{"data-bind" => item.name"}
    %a.btn{"data-route" => "routes.projects[project].tables[table].items[item]"} View details »
```

The Problem here is with the link tag:

```
Uncaught DevelopmentError: Couldn't find a route for the name items!
```

But the name of the item in the p tag is displayed correctly. something is wrong with my routes. Has anyone an idea of multiple nested routes in BatmanJS ?

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed, it doesn't work more than two levels deep.  There are no tests that have more than two levels, so this may be by design.